# Is it good or bad practice to put a class object in a session variable? (PHP)

Tags: php, class, session

I was recently experimenting with a "User.class" which handles login and logout (and some other functions). Login was easy to get to work, but logout was worse, because i didnt maintain the $user - object which i had declared in the beginning. Which took me way to long to understand.

I have a button for "log out", and i wanted to use my class to "do stuff" when i logged out. One way could be to do a classic one :

```
if(isset($_GET["logout"])) {
     //do stuff in db
     session_destroy();
     header("Location: index.php");
}
```

but since i was using class and functions in that class, i wanted to call

```
if(isset($_GET["logout"])) {
      $user->logOut();
}
```

But this didnt work. As said.

I found out that i could, after login, save the object in a serialized sessionvariable.

```
if(isset($_GET["login"])) {
$user = new User($dbh, $_POST["uid"], $_POST["key"]);

$r = $user->login();
$_SESSION["userObj"] = serialize($user);

}
if(isset($_GET["logout"])) {
    $user = unserialize($_SESSION["userObj"]);
    $user->logOut();
}
```

And, this is working. 
But i think, i am handling this quite, bad on the "User.class" page, where i have this code:

```
public function __sleep() {
    return array("login_id", "uid");
}

public function __wakeup() {
    include_once("conn.php");
    global $dbh;
    $this->db = $dbh;
    unset($dbh);
}
```

As you see, i have my database connection in another file, and during __wakeup(), i need to reinitialize the database conneciton.

Question is, is this good or bad practice? 
This is totally new for me... :)

Comment: For this type of service, i believe the user would be online at max 1 hour, this aint like no community or something.